# How to use Objective-C classes with names which are keywords in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, naming

We are trying to use the BZObjectStore library (https://github.com/expensivegasprices/BZObjectStore) in our Swift project.

But in this library, they use 'where' as a name to set the query conditions.

```
BZObjectStoreConditionModel *fetchCondition = [BZObjectStoreConditionModel condition];
fetchCondition.sqlite.where = @"name = 'sample1' and price > 50";
fetchCondition.sqlite.orderBy = @"name desc";

NSArray *objects = [os fetchObjects:[SampleModel class] condition:fetchCondition error:&error];
```

But unfortunately, 'where' is a keyword in Swift. We do not want to change the code in BZObjectStore manually. So is there any way we can resolve this ?

Comment: We found the solution.

var condition = BZObjectStoreConditionModel.condition()
condition.sqlite.\`where\`= "1+1"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use backticks:

```
fetchCondition.sqlite.`where` = @"name = 'sample1' and price > 50";
```

> To use a reserved word as an identifier, put a backtick (`) before and after it. For example, class is not a valid identifier, but `class` is valid. The backticks are not considered part of the identifier; `x` and x have the same meaning.

[The Swift Programming Language – Lexical Structure](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html)